# What is the purpose of "Tracing" settings in Google Chrome Canary?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I use Chrome Canary and I found an option named 'Tracing' in Chrome > Settings > Developer options. The option doesn't exist in stable Chrome version and I guess it exists in Beta and Dev releases.

The option has 3 segments (see image)

[image]

Here are some checkboxes inside every option:

[image]
[image]

What is the purpose of this option? Maybe bug reporting or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In software development, tracing is the process of logging information while a program is running or executed. It serves mainly to debug a program.

In case of [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool) (or Chrome I presume)

> When diagnosing performance problems it can be valuable to see what Chrome is doing "under the hood." One way to get a more detailed view into what's going on is to use the about:tracing tool.
>
> Tracing records activity in Chrome's processes (see multi-process architecture for more on what each process is doing). It records C++ or javascript method signatures in a hierarchical view for each thread in each process. This is a lot of information, but sifting through it can help identify performance bottlenecks, slow operations, and events with irregular lengths (leading to e.g. framerate variation).

This is just what is happening with Chrome Canary.
The categories selected are those the apps will log information, details while running that will help the developers diagnose potential problems with the app.